# Triangle inequality for weighted norms

Tags: matrix-norms

I am trying to prove or disprove the triangle inequality for the function:

$f(X) = \sqrt{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{d}\frac{|X_{k}|^{2}}{k}}$ ; where $X \in R^{d}$.

I tried whatever I could, and my calculations are shown below. I want to know if we can take it any further from there or is there some other way to find the result.

$$f(X + Y) = \sqrt{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{d}\frac{|X_{k} + Y_{k}|^{2}}{k}}$$
According to Minkowski Inequality, $\sqrt{a^{2}} + \sqrt{b^{2}} \geq \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$
$$
\implies f(X + Y) \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{d}\sqrt{\frac{|X_{k} + Y_{k}|^{2}}{k}} 
          = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{d}\frac{|X_{k} + Y_{k}|}{k}
          \\ \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^{d}\frac{|X_{k}|}{\sqrt{k}} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{d}\frac{|Y_{k}|}{\sqrt{k}}
          = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{d}\sqrt{\frac{|X_{k}|^{2}}{k}} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{d}\sqrt{\frac{|Y_{k}|^{2}}{k}}
$$

If we further try to solve by applying Minkowski Inequality again, we will get $\geq$ and that would mean that we are not reaching any meaningful conclusion...

Comment: First use $\vert X_k + Y_k\vert^2 \leq \vert X_k\vert^2 + \vert Y_k \vert^2$, and then use Minkowski's inequality (which is here just subadditivity of the square root)

Comment: Define $\tilde{x}_k=X_kk^{-1/2}.$ Then $f(X)=\|\tilde{x}\|.$ Hence the triangle inequality follows.

Comment: @stange Are you sure that the inequality in your comment holds? Take $X_k=Y_k=1.$

Comment: Thanks a lot @RyszardSzwarc . It definitely makes sense now. Never thought the proof was that easy.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Oh, yeah, my brain must have disconnected there.